# My bootstrap drop down not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I just copied the bootstrap 4 drop-down list code from w3schools.com. But the drop-down is not working in my visual studio code. Though,that code is working in the online editor. Please tell me if I am missing something as I am a beginner.
Here is my Code:

```
 `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Bootstrap4/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Bootstrap4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Bootstrap4/css/flexboxgrid.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center" style="background-color:#00061a;">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>  
    </ul>
    </div> 

</div> <!-- End of container -->

<script src="../Bootstrap4/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Bootstrap4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: have you checked in your network to see if bootstrap is loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bootstrap 4

you have to use `id="dropdownMenuButton" on you a/button tag`

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
    id="dropdownMenuButton"  href="#">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I have added the Id also in the 'a' link but still it is not working. Just so you know that I am using bootstrap 4 beta version in my project. Thanks.

Comment: My drop down started working as soon as I added popper.min.js file in my project. Since it was not present in my compiled css and jss version. I had to download whole bootstrap 4 beta version file and from there I copied that 'popper' file inside my project. Anyway thank you so much.